# Como testar name-based virtual servers/SNI numa máquina local?

Tags: testes, domínio, webserver

Estou migrando do Apache pro nginx, e de um certificado "curinga" (*wildcard certificate* - um único certificado para vários domínios) para [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Gostaria de testar a nova configuração localmente (de preferência via Vagrant - meu server usa FreeBSD e minha máquina local usa Windows 7, mas isso é por minha conta, não faz parte da pergunta). É possível?

Esclarecendo: posso acessar minha instalação local via `localhost` ou `127.0.0.1` ou usando o IP da minha máquina. Gostaria entretanto de testar usando diferentes nomes de domínio - como se fosse um único servidor hospedando diversos sites - ainda que não necessariamente os mesmos que serão usados em produção (mas de preferência sim, pois simplificaria os testes do SNI). Já que o objetivo é verificar se os servidores virtuais *name-based* e seus certificados estão funcionando corretamente (i.e. a configuração do webserver também é por minha conta).